# How to have in document (as document content/printed) table of content in beggining of document

Tags: ruby, prawn

During generation of document I will store my *TOC* (Table of Contents) entries... structure looks something like this (hashes stored in array):

```
[
 {:title => "Page Title" , :page_no => 15},
 {:title => "Page Title 2" , :page_no => 22}
]
```

At the end of document I use it to generate *TOC*. All worked great until...

**Now I have to generate** that same *TOC* **at the beggining** of document as 2nd page of the document (insert it in beggining behind title page). And this is where I seem to have hit a dead end.

As I do not know how many pages that *TOC* will have until I have actually generated it I do not know the new page numbers content will have (after being shifted by *TOC*)...

Any ideas how to handle *TOC* at the beggining of the document properly?

Comment: Do the same thing as you would do to generate it at the end, but insert it into the start of the array instead of the end, eg with `unshift`

Comment: If i unserstand correctly what you mean it doesn't solve my problem... i will insert pages (at the beggining) and therefore I do not know page numbers of everything after (as they shifted by unknown number of pages)

Comment: http://prawnpdf.org/manual.pdf Page 96 might help

Comment: Well that I am using already. However that will generate clickable outline in PDF viewer. Not in Document TOC that actually gets printed when you print PDF.